# Suggested tag synonym: [sw-the-old-republic] and [swtor]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have two tags for the *Star Wars: The Old Republic* MMO:

- [sw-the-old-republic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-the-old-republic)
- [swtor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swtor)

Since [sw-the-old-republic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-the-old-republic) has six questions and two followers, and [swtor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swtor) only has three questions (one of which is *also* tagged [sw-the-old-republic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-the-old-republic)) and zero followers, I suggest making [swtor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swtor) a synonym.

You can vote for the synonym [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/sw-the-old-republic/synonyms).

On a related note (since there are currently only two users with enough answer score to vote on this), should we expand the scope of [sw-the-old-republic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-the-old-republic) to include the entire *Knights of the Old Republic* sub-franchise?

Comment: are people likely to continue trying to use both tags in the future? if not, would it be easier to just retag the three [tag:swtor] and let it die?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I tend to see "SWTOR" used to refer to the series, in the same way people use "LOTR" for *Lord of the Rings*; it would be easier to just delete it, but I think it makes sense as a synonym anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we lack the users to make this happen without mod help, I'll just synonymize them.